# Decay time to constant function of heat kernel on 2-sphere

Tags: manifolds, linear-pde, heat-equation

Let us consider solving the heat equation on the sphere given a delta function as initial data.

$$(\partial_t - \Delta)K(x,y;t) = 0 $$

$$K(x,y;0) = \delta(x,y)$$

One would expect that for large times, the kernel would be a uniform distribution with respect to the metric on the sphere as it spreads across for larger times.

$$K(x,y;t) \approx \frac{\sqrt{det[g(y)]}}{V}, t \gg 0$$
Where the $V$ is the volume of the sphere,
$$V = \int_{S^2} \sqrt{det[g]}$$

One would expect this from a physical standpoint, since this is saying that a probability distribution on a sphere evolving by diffusing across the sphere would become approximately uniform for long times.

My question is if there is any time scale that would dictate how long the kernel takes to reach a "near uniform" state. For a more specific question, are there any known estimates of quantities such as the how an error $\epsilon(t)$ between the heat kernel at time t differs fromits final state changes in time? For example, if

$$\epsilon(t)=\int_{S^2} ||K(x,0;\infty)-K(x,0;t)|| \sqrt{det[g]}d^2x$$

And can we answer questions like how long does it take for $\epsilon(t)$ to get close to zero, or what are its asymptotics as $t \rightarrow \infty$? Has anyone done numerical investigations of this?

[This user asked a similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253829/long-time-decay-of-heat-kernel-on-compact-manifolds)  for manifolds with boundary, but the answers there don't seem to pertain to this question.

Comment: do you mean "on the sphere" (with standard metric) or "on a sphere" (with arbitrary metric $g$)?

Comment: I was more interested in the standard metric, but if there are answers for arbitrary metrics that may be interesting too.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of the standard metrics on the sphere, you can actually write everything explicitly using spherical harmonics. Namely, for each $l=0,1,2,\dots$, the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the sphere has $2l+1$ eigenfunctions $Y_l^{-m},\dots,Y_l^m$ with eigenvalue $l(l+1)$. Therefore,
$$
K(\theta,\varphi,t)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^la_l^me^{-l(l+1)t}Y_l^{m}(\theta,\varphi),
$$
where the coefficients $a_l^m$ are computed from the initial conditions, 
$$
a_l^m=Y_l^m(0,0).
$$
In fact, from the explicit expressions for $Y_l^m$ in terms of associated Legendre polynomials, you can see that $a_l^m=0$ for $m\neq 0$, and $|a_l^0|\sim\text{const}$ as $l$ goes to infinity (I'm getting $a_l^0=\pm \frac{\sqrt{2l+1}}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{(l-1)!!}{l!!}$, but I may have miscalculated).

From this, you easily get 
$$
||K(\cdot,\cdot,t)-K(\cdot,\cdot,\infty)||_\infty \leq Ce^{-2t},
$$ 
and $C$ is a not-so-big numerical constant.